# Django forms show cleaned data if validation fails

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following function declared in a django form:

```
def clean_name(self):
    name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
    name = re.sub('\s+', ' ', name).strip().title()
    return name
```

I have an unique constraint on the name field and I would like to have the name trimmed in the form if the validation hits.

What is the proper way to do that in Django?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I've read some articles, finally i came to this solution, to override the full_clean method:

```
def full_clean(self):
    cleaned_data = {}
    for i,v in self.data.items():
        if isinstance(v, basestring):
            cleaned_data[i] = re.sub('\s+', ' ', v).strip()
        else:
            cleaned_data[i] = v
    self.data = cleaned_data

    super(MyForm, self).full_clean()
```

It works, but it looks kind of dirty to me, anyother suggestions?